# Problem with linking in gcc

Tags: gcc

I am compiling a program in which a header file is defined in multiple places. Contents of each of the header file is different, though the variable names are the same internal members within the structures are different .

Now at the linking time it is picking up from a library file which belongs to a different header not the one which is used during compilation. Due to this I get an error at link time.

Since there are so many libraries with the same name I don't know which library is being picked up. I have lot of oems and other customized libraries which are part of this build.

I checked out the options in gcc which talks about selecting different library files to be included. But no where I am able to see an option which talks about which libraries are being picked up the linker.

If the linker is able to find more than one library file name, then which does the linker pick up is something which I am not able to understand. I don't want to specify any path, rather I want to understand how the linker is resolving the multiple libraries that it is able to locate. I tried putting -v option, but that doesn't list out the path from which the gcc picks up the library.

I am using gcc on linux.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Chitra

Comment: How do you define a header file in multiple places?  Do you mean "include?"  What error are you getting?

Comment: Plz add linker output, and possibly your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `-Wl,-t` to gcc will tell ld to dump which files it's reading.